# R: editing character string vector with /r/n to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, character

I want to make some pdf-**scraping** and to read faster the **scraped** text I want to convert long vector with characters to data.frame
Let's have a character string vector:

```
  pdf <- c("123\r\naaa\r\nbbb\r\n")
```

I want to remove "\r\n" and each line insert in separated row in data frame.
What to do to obtain the following outcome:

```
  #expected outcome
    #[,1]
    #[1,]123
    #[2,]aaa
    #[3,]bbb
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read.table` to create a data frame:

```
read.table(text = pdf)
#    V1
# 1 123
# 2 aaa
# 3 bbb
```